# Read array from embedded DLL c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dll, embedded

I wrote code in my class like below and built as `SmartUser.DLL`

```
namespace SmartUser
{
    public class User
    {
        private static string _companyName = "Company Amazon";
        private static string [] _userName = {"Mr. Anam", "Mr. Beat", 
                                              "Miss. Jane"};

        public static string CompanyName
        {
            get { return _companyName; }
            set { _companyName = value; }
        }
        public static string[] UserName
        {
            get { return _userName[]; }
            set { _userName= value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and I create another C# project `myApp` with my method named `My_DLL` to read the data from `SmartUser.DLL`.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public string Licensed_Company;
    public string [] Licensed_User;

    public void My_DLL()
    {
        Assembly UserDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(WinForm.Application.StartupPath + @"\User\SmartUser.dll");          
        Type UserClass = UserDLL.GetType("SmartUser.User");

        PropertyInfo company_PropertyInfo = UserClass.GetProperty("CompanyName");
        //--- Pass my string CompanyName store in SmartUser to Licensed_Company
        Licensed_Company = (string) company_PropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);

        PropertyInfo user_PropertyInfo = UserClass.GetProperty("UserName");
        //--- Pass my string CompanyName store in SmartUser to Licensed_Company
        Licensed_User[] = (string) user_PropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
    }
}
```

I was successful to read data for string `CompanyName` but I couldn't be able to read from String Array `UserName`

So what can I do to pass the array from `SmartUser.dll` into myApp via my method's named `My_DLL()` ?

Thank advance.

Thank advance.

Comment: Why not do it just like you are currently doing for `Licensed_Company`? It will work the same. Have you tried _anything_? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? This question is not clear at all

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterDuniho
I tried this :
    PropertyInfo user_PropertyInfo = UserClass.GetProperty("UserName");
    Licensed_User = (string) user_PropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
but it didn't work

Comment: Do not use the comments to add information to your question. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39564891/edit) the post instead. **Do** provide a more specific problem description than "it didn't work". State clearly what happened, and how that is different from what you wanted to happen instead. Note that since the property is a `string[]` value, and you do in fact want a `string[]` value, you should cast the result of the call to `GetValue()` to `string[]` instead of `string` (as you say in the comment that you are doing).

Comment: @PeterDuniho so much thank, now I found the problem as your idea that is cast `string[]` , This is my first time to join this community. once again thank you.